# how to add duplicated woocommerce product options to each simple product under grouped products

Tags: php, wordpress, web, woocommerce

I want to add a checkbox for the product to indicate if needs assemble or not,if yes, then more money will be charged. My products are shown as grouped style, like:
[image]

I am using a plugin called woocommerce extra product options, which can add the checkbox before "add to cart" button. As:

[image]

But I want to add the checkbox to each line of the simple products under the grouped product instead of only one; like:

[image]

I checked the documentaion, it says use following to hook the extra item in the code/page you want.

```
function my_custom_function(){
    do_action("woocommerce_tm_epo");
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button','my_custom_function');
```

But I tried, it always shows only one before add to cart button regardless how many time "add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button','my_custom_function');" it is called. How can I achieve my goal? Thanks in advance.

I also tried do_action("woocommerce_tm_epo"); only, but it is not showing anything. If I use do_action("woocommerce_tm_epo"), from screen I can see the space for the checkbox, but just showing the blank. I checked the firebug, I can see the checkbox is there, but for some reason is being hidden. I checked the corresponding CSS, find one place Visbility:hidden; after I changed it to visbility:visable. Still shows blank. Already sitting on the chair for this more than 13 hours, hope someone can help or provide helpful advices.